# Python pandas: Add column to grouped DataFrame with method chaining

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

First let say that i'm new to pandas .

I am trying to make a new column in a DataFrame. I am able to do this as shown in my example. But I want to do this by chaining methods, so I don't have to assign new variables. Let me first show what I want to achieve, and what I have done this so far:

```
In [1]:
import numpy as np
from pandas import Series,DataFrame
import pandas as pd

In [2]:
np.random.seed(10)
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('ABC'))
df

Out [2]:
A  B  C
2  2  1
4  1  2
4  1  2
2  1  2
2  3  1
2  1  3
1  3  1
4  1  1
4  4  3
1  4  3
In [3]:
filtered_DF = df[df['B']<2].copy()
grouped_DF = filtered_DF.groupby('A')
filtered_DF['C_Share_By_Group'] =filtered_DF.C.div(grouped_DF.C.transform("sum"))
filtered_DF

Out [3]:
A  B  C  C_Share_By_Group
4  1  2               0.4
4  1  2               0.4
2  1  2               0.4
2  1  3               0.6
4  1  1               0.2
```

I want to achieve the same thing by chaining methods. In R with dplyr package, I would be able to do something like:

```
df %>% 
  filter(B<2) %>%
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate('C_Share_By_Group'=C/sum(C))
```

In the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_r.html#transforming) it says that `mutate` in R(dplyr) is equal to `assign` in pandas, but `assign` doesn't work on a grouped object. 
 When I try to assign something to grouped dataframe, I get an error:

> "AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'assign' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method"

I have tried the following, but don't know how to add the new column, or if it is even possible to achieve this by chaining methods:

```
(df.loc[df.B<2]
   .groupby('A')
    #****WHAT GOES HERE?**** apply(something)?
)
```

Comment: Welcome to the sad world from functional to imperative programming. You can use transform in Python

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
print df[df['B']<2].assign(C_Share_By_Group=lambda df: 
                       df.C
                         .div(df.groupby('A')
                           .C
                           .transform("sum")))

   A  B  C  C_Share_By_Group
1  4  1  2               0.4
2  4  1  2               0.4
3  2  1  2               0.4
5  2  1  3               0.6
7  4  1  1               0.2
```

Comment: Thank you for trying. I just don't think this is really the answer I was looking for. One of  the beauties of method chaining is, that you don't have to do things twice, as you are passing the output of the method along.
In your approach you are filtering the same DataFrame three times (`df['B']<2]`).

Comment: Thanks. You are right, so answer was edited and unnecessary code removed. Please check it now.

Comment: I tried running your code, but the result is not equal to my code.

C_Share_By_Group
        0.250000

        0.250000

        0.285714

        0.428571

        0.125000

Comment: You forget `lambda` I think.

Comment: No. But I think I found the mistake. You group 'df' by A, not the lambda x. That fixed it :)

Comment: OOPs, you are rigtht. I try edit answer to nice one;)  see [revision](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37142374/revisions), there is original `df`.

Comment: I'll accept your answer although it wasn't exactly what I was looking for. I guess in order to do what I want more methods has to be added to the `DataFrameGroupBy` class. Hopefully they will add these later on just as they improved method chaining with 0.18.1.